# Internet connection lost after installing dnsmasq

Tags: dnsmasq, access-point

I'm currently trying to set up an access point on my raspberry pi, but as soon as I install 'dnsmasq', the internet connection is lost ('unknown host' when trying to ping any server).

What causes this and how do I connect it to the internet again?

P.S.: i can access it via ssh, so local network is still working...

**edit:** so apparently it's just the dns-server, because it works when pinging the numeric ip instead of e.g. google.com; I assume the dnsmasq/nscd service is overwriting the working configuration

Comment: I believe what dnsmasq does is set your DNS address to `127.0.0.1`, which dnsmasq listens to, and then it forwards the query to the appropriate external server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure `dnsmasq`.  Look in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`. I don't know much about your situation, but I'm certain that you'll need to set these options:

```
resolv-file=/etc/dnsmasq.resolv
listen-address=127.0.0.1
listen-address=10.0.0.3  # Or whatever the machine's IP address is.
```

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` is what every process other than `dnsmasq` looks into to find what IP address to send a DNS query to. On the machine running `dnsmasq`, `/etc/resolv.conf` should have it's own IP address in `resolv.conf`.

Then, you need to have `/etc/dnsmasq.resolv` containing the IP address of the next level up's DNS server. That might be your company's DNS server, or your ISP's DNS server, or something like 8.8.8.8, or whoever you use.

I have a superstition that after changing `dnsmasq.conf` or `dnsmasq-resolv`, you have to stop and start the `dnsmasq` process. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

dnsmasq should read `/etc/resolv.conf` and use the DNS servers there. In case that doesn't work for some reason, you can manually specify what DNS servers to use. To do that, in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, add `server=` followed by the IP address of the DNS server. For example, to use `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` as your DNS servers, use:

```
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```